# ie6 positionning

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

here is the page : http://missfrisette.com/index.php#

the top white box, should be 35 pixel from the top and the should be to the left... do the header is in wrong position.... only in ie

the inline trick dont work ... any idea ?

Comment: putting all the box relatif and top xx px made it... remove margin because it dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin top for this id is 0

```
#headerbox {
margin-top:35px;

}
```

Comment: yep headerbox should be to the top.. header (without box at the ens) have the margin-top... but it dont respect it !

Comment: for me both ie and firefox , headerbox hits the top, try to give margin top and see if that fixes your problem.